# What is Stephen Chow working on post Journey to the West?

Tags: stephen-chow

This question refers to the movie produces/director/actor - [Stephen Chow](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0159507/)

After 2013's - [Journey to the West](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2017561/?ref_=nm_flmg_dr_1), there seems to be no word of any upcoming projects by Stephen Chow.

Does anyone know of a future project he might be working on?
Also, is there a reason he has so much gap between his movies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Mermaid](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4701660/?ref_=nm_flmg_dr_1)  2016

According to IMDB it is the most recent work related to him. the gap between his recent works have increased as you see also 3 year between CJ7 and journey to the  west.it's not too unusual(Some directors like to work more precisely and spend more time for their work).

Comment: Ah finally, I was worried if he had some health issue or something. Good to know he's back!